# Display No Results Message Flexigid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

So I hide my Flexigrid until there are search match results.

So my flexigrid intialization:

```
flexigrid({
        url ='myUrl',  
        onSubmit: showFlexigrid(),
        //my other flexigrid options
        });

 function showFlexigrid(celDiv, id) {

        var flexiGrid = $('#gridTablegSearchProperty')

        if (!flexiGrid.is(":visible")) {
            if (id) { //got at least one result if id is not undefined
                $('#flexigridWrapper').show();
            } else {
                //I want to display a no results found message to the user here
                //but this won't work because the showFlexigrid function is
                //not called on flexiReload()
                console.log('no results');
            }
        }
    }

//in my $document.ready my search button click implementation:

 $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    $('#gridTablegSearchProperty').flexReload();
  });

<!--And my html-->
<div id="flexigridWrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="well-inner">
                    <table id="gridTablegSearchProperty"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So whether it is flexigrid onSubmit or onSuccess that I bind to in my flexigrid "instantiation" neither is called on .flexReload unless at least on record is returned. I see no flexigrid option that is trigged every time, not even onSubmit does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of a quotation mark related syntax issue with the click event in your `$(document).ready()`. Have a look at the [jQuery style guide for quotes](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#quotes). It reads: "Strings that require inner quoting must use double outside and single inside."

Comment: Thanks!, that is just a typo in my stackoverflow question, my code works and is syntactically correct, just having an issue finding a way to show my own custom no results message.